# OpenLayers Control ScaleLine - show only meters

Tags: openlayers

I have an application that uses `OpenLayers` library.

I create a scale line:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());
```

But it shows both meters and fs. I need to show only meters.
I add next code to openlayers.css

```
.olControlScaleLineBottom {
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

But it still shows ft. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable top or bottom part of scaleline by setting topOutUnits or bottomOutUnits to empty string:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({bottomOutUnits: ''}));
```

That behavior is not mentioned in documentation, but you can find it easily, when you look at control's source code.